# Data store in C used by multiple files

Tags: c, header-files

I have a huge array of type-def which I want it to be accessible across multiple c files. The definition of type-def is in header file. What is the best approach for sharing the data .. should I store it in a header file or in a c file ?

Approach I

```
project.h
---------
typedef struct td_myproject{
    lot of fields .... 
} td_myproject;

projectdata.h
-------------
include "project.h"

td_myproject myproject[] = {
    over 100k of recs with data filled before compilation
}

myproject.c
-----------
include "project.h"
include "projectdata.h"
(with proper guard usage)

print(%s",myproject[0].field1);
```

Approach 2

```
project.h
---------
typedef struct td_myproject{
    lot of fields .... 
} td_myproject;

projectdata.c
-------------
include "project.h"

td_myproject myproject[] = {
    over 100k of recs with data filled before compilation
}

myproject.c
-----------
include "project.h"
(with proper guard usage)

print(%s",myproject[0].field1);
```

Comment: Is the data static or is it ever likely to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, and this really is a personal choice, I would store the data (`myproject[]`) in its own C file.

Why?

Because conceptually header files should be for constants (use for compilation, not storage) and definitions.

Code files, on the other hand, consist of data and code. Ultimately code files compile down to object files and the linker then joins up references between those object files. Both code and data are items that are referenced so - logically - if your data is in a C file which then becomes an object file it will be referenced by another object file (from a C file).

For me the test of whether something can go in a header file is whether two separate C files could include that file and still link. In this case - putting a static variable in a header file would break linkage if included in two different C files.

So how to best approach this?

Header file `myproject.h`:

```
include "project.h"

/* define variable type, and the fact it needs to be linked in */
extern td_myproject myproject[];
```

Code file `myprojectdata.c`:

```
#include "myproject.h"

/* actually define contents of variable in this unit */
td_myproject myproject[] = { ... };
```

The advantage of this is that you can then reference `myproject[]` from other C files by merely including `myproject.h`.

Code file `myproject.c`:

```
#include "myproject.h"

int main( void ) {
    print("%s",myproject[0].field1);
}
```

Linking:

```
gcc -o myproject myproject.c myprojectdata.c
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see in first approach is that, in file myproject.c you have included both .h files, with

include "project.h"
include "projectdata.h"

But your "projectdata.h" already includes "project.h" so you may want to remove a instance of inclusion of  "project.h" from you .c file.

And in approad II, how myproject.c would know what is myproject[]. So how about declaring myproject[] a extern in myproject.c as it is already declared in projectdata.c?